# MySQL Left Join (I think) Difficulty

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    u.username as username, 
    s.campaignno as campaign, 
    if(f.hometeamscore>f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Win, 
    if(f.hometeamscore=f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Draw, 
    if(f.hometeamscore<f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Loss, 
    f.hometeamscore as Goals, 
    ss.seasonid as Season, 
    av.avatar as Avatar 
FROM 
    avatar_avatar av, 
    straightred_fixture f, 
    straightred_userselection s, 
    auth_user u, 
    straightred_season ss 
WHERE 
        av.user_id = u.id 
    AND ss.seasonid = 1025 
    AND f.soccerseasonid = ss.seasonid 
    AND s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid 
    AND s.teamselectionid = f.hometeamid 
    AND s.user_id = u.id;
```

This query is working as expected but I have now realised that a user may not have uploaded a profile picture.  So the following part `av.user_id = u.id` is excluding anyone who has NOT uploaded a profile picture.  I feel i need to use a left join after reading the following `https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp` but I just keep going around in circles and get nowhere.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

Comment: You're right, you need a left join. Using all tables on the `FROM` statement is the same as using `INNER JOIN`, so you need to add a `LEFT JOIN` of the table in question. Besides, code indentation goes a long way to better understand SQL. Also, take a look at this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: What have you tried? It should involve little more than replacing all those ancient commas in your FROM with `[INNER|LEFT] JOIN` and moving the corresponding join conditions out of the WHERE and into the ON clauses the appropriate joins. _It also usually helps if the tables joined are listed as adjacent to each other as possible._

Comment: Code indentation is a simple yet clever idea, I will go ahead and do that while following both your suggestions. Many thanks, will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: **avoid** implicit `JOIN`s. Make `JOIN`s explicit and you will make much more clear which entity relates to which entity, and you'll never forget to add one of the `AND` conditions in your `WHERE` and get a cartesian product.

Second: try to put your tables in the `FROM` using an order that follows a certain logic. In your case, you seem to start looking for `ss.seasonid = 1025`... (it's the only condition on the `WHERE` having a constant). Then, your list of conditions produces a certain logical order... Each table in the `FROM` has a relationship with the previous one...

That said, I think you need this query:

```
SELECT 
    u.username as username, 
    s.campaignno as campaign, 
    if(f.hometeamscore>f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Win, 
    if(f.hometeamscore=f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Draw, 
    if(f.hometeamscore<f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Loss, 
    f.hometeamscore as Goals, 
    ss.seasonid as Season, 
    av.avatar as Avatar 
FROM
    straightred_season ss 
    JOIN straightred_fixture f 
        ON f.soccerseasonid = ss.seasonid  
    JOIN straightred_userselection s 
        ON s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid AND s.teamselectionid = f.hometeamid 
    JOIN auth_user u 
        ON u.id = s.user_id
    -- This last table is the one that needs to be LEFT-joined
    -- if the avatar is *optional*. If it isn't there, av.avatar will just
    -- be shown as NULL
    LEFT JOIN avatar_avatar av 
        ON av.user_id = u.id  
WHERE 
    ss.seasonid = 1025 ;
```

If the content of more tables is *optional*, you may need more than one `LEFT JOIN`. In order to find out what makes sense, we would need to have the full data model, or the ERD, that represents your scenario. That is, which relationships are 1 to 1, which are 1 to Many, which are 1 to (0 or 1), which are Many-to-Many, etc.

Comment: This feels like where I was trying to get to and makes complete sense.  No more tables are optional.  Many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of using JOIN's so I rewrote your query like this.

Be advised however that I user SQL SERVER / ORACLE and not MYSQL so not sure if my semantics are correct. I use the **IFNULL** function since at least in my world, using a column where the row isn't available can cause the entire result to filter out.

Also by moving **ss.seasonid = 1025** into the join, rather than leaving it in the **where**, you should get results regardless of there existing an **ss** record.

That said, this should resolve your issues:

**EDIT - replace ISNULL with IFNULL**

```
select
 u.username as username
,s.campaignno as campaign
,if(ifnull(f.hometeamscore,0)>ifnull(f.awayteamscore,0),1,0) as Win
,if(ifnull(f.hometeamscore,0)=ifnull(f.awayteamscore,-1),1,0) as Draw
,if(ifnull(f.hometeamscore,0)<ifnull(f.awayteamscore,0),1,0) as Loss
,f.hometeamscore as Goals
,ss.seasonid as Season
,av.avatar as Avatar
from
 auth_user                 u
Left Join 
 avatar_avatar             av on u.id = av.user_id
Left Join
 straightred_userselection s  on u.id =  s.user_id
Left Join
 straightred_fixture       f  on f.hometeamid = s.teamselectionid
                             and f.fixtureid  = s.fixtureid
Left Join
 straightred_season        ss on f.soccerseasonid = ss.seasonid
                             and ss.seasonid = 1025
```

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive reply.  I got the following error "ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'" (I appreciate you said you was not using MySql) but I understand the thought process on layout.  Many thanks.

Comment: my bad... use **IFNULL**... and again, if no records in table **f**, you'll run into issues, which is why I included the **IFNULL**  functions. The other thing too is, imho, the **auth_user** seems to be the primary table so, all other tables should defer to it - i think!.